# Filling eigen matrix with values

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, ros

sorry to bother. Could you know maybe how can i fix my code. It gives me this error:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:365: Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar& Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::operator()(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar = float; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `row >= 0 && row < rows() && col >= 0 && col < cols()' failed.
```

I think that I declared matrix in right way. My mistake (I think) is when i try to fill her with values in Possible transforms function. I think it might be wrong transform1(0, position)=.. I tried it to comment that lines of code and wrote a simple code like transform1(0, position)=1; and it gave the same error.

Sorry to bother,
Kind regards.

My code :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex>
#include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h"
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h>
#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/PointField.h"
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include "eigen3/Eigen/SVD"
#include "eigen3/Eigen/Dense"
#include "clustering/Track.h"
#include "eigen3/Eigen/Core"
#include "eigen3/Eigen/Sparse"
using namespace Eigen;

int number_od_possible_tracks = 15;

class Odometry_class {
ros::NodeHandle nodeh;
ros::Subscriber sub;
ros::Publisher pub;

public: 
Odometry_class();
void Odometry(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &msg); 
bool Has_pointcloud_min3points(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> cloud);
bool Possible_transform(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> cloud);
void Restore_Ids();
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> last_cloud;
Eigen::MatrixXf transform1 = (Eigen::MatrixXf(3,15));
Eigen::MatrixXf transform2=(Eigen::MatrixXf(3,15));
int consecutive_Ids_current[15];
int consecutive_Ids_previous[15];
int position;
void Transform();
};


Odometry_class::Odometry_class(){
sub = nodeh.subscribe("trackers", 10, &Odometry_class::Odometry, this); 
pub = nodeh.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odometry", 10); 

}

void Odometry_class::Odometry(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &msg ){
pcl::PCLPointCloud2 pcl_pc2;
pcl_conversions::toPCL(msg, pcl_pc2);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> cloud;
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2, cloud); 

if(Possible_transform(cloud)){
ROS_INFO("Transformation is possible");
}
else{
ROS_INFO("Transformation is not possible");
}

Restore_Ids();
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(pcl_pc2, last_cloud); 
}




void Odometry_class::Restore_Ids(){
int i=0;
while(consecutive_Ids_current[i]!=0){
consecutive_Ids_current[i]=0;
consecutive_Ids_previous[i]=0;
i++;
}

}

bool Odometry_class::Has_pointcloud_min3points(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> cloud){
bool has=false;
if(cloud.width>=3){
has=true;
}
return has;
}


bool Odometry_class::Possible_transform(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZIVSI> cloud){
bool possible=false;
position=0;
if(Has_pointcloud_min3points(cloud)&Has_pointcloud_min3points(last_cloud)){ 
for(int i=0;i<cloud.width;i++){
for(int j=0;j<last_cloud.width;j++){
if(cloud[i].id==last_cloud[j].id){
consecutive_Ids_current[position]=i;
consecutive_Ids_previous[position]=j;
position++;
}
}
}
}

if(position>=3){
possible=true;
transform1.resize(3,position);
transform2.resize(3,position);

for(int i=0;i<position;i++){

transform1(0,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_current[i]].x;
transform1(1,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_current[i]].y;
transform1(2,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_current[i]].z;
transform2(0,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_previous[i]].x;
transform2(1,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_previous[i]].y;
transform2(2,position)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_previous[i]].z;
}

}

return possible;
}




int main(int argc, char **argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "Odometry");
Odometry_class Odometry; 

ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should try provide a minimal working example of your code by removing pieces of code that don't cause a problem. During the process, you may get lucky and find the problem on your own in the first place, thus avoiding the necessity to post a question in the first place. As well, it helps others solve your problems, because they can run your program (or attempt to do so anyway). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed up your loop variable, `i`, and upper limit, `position`. Using `position` as an index would result in accessing the matrix out of bounds, and the Eigen library catches that in an assertion. Using the loop variable should resolve the error.

```
transform1(0,i)= cloud[consecutive_Ids_current[i]].x;
```

And likewise for the rest of the `transform1` and `transform2` assignments.

Comment: Oh, I see it, how  I didn't saw that.Thank you very much!